# Google maps padding does not take into account my location

Tags: android, google-maps, padding, mylocationoverlay

[image]
i have applied padding to google maps from bottom , it takes into consideration google logo and my location square button.
But unfortunately  it does not take into consideration my location blue circle (blue dot at center) it does not move up (google logo and my location square button shifts up)

Comment: can you show your problem

Comment: please provide screenshots..

Comment: @OnkarNene , have updated screenshot

Comment: @VivekMishra i have updated the screen shots

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339365/googlemaps-api-3-fitbounds-padding

Comment: @d.datul1990 it's not the issue i am facing.

Comment: my blue dot and map does not get adjust accordingly when i am updating the padding for map whether in case of my ios app its working fine i.e The change of padding also affect the map view and it's blue dot.

Comment: did you solve it? I am having the same problem. Th google logo, direction icon etc are padded but not the actual map.