# WpCasa Map, avoid fitBounds() Zoom too close for single marker

Tags: wordpress

Looking at this question [Google Maps v3 fitBounds() Zoom too close for single marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334729/google-maps-v3-fitbounds-zoom-too-close-for-single-marker)

seems the easy way is to pass maxZoom option

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { maxZoom: 14 });
```

Looking at the source code of the plugin, seems there is a hook for that `wpsight_listings_map_options`

Now I'm confused on how to use the hook.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I found my way... and perhaps it could help others.

Here is what I've added to functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wpsight_listings_map_options', 'wpsight_listings_maxZoom' );
function wpsight_listings_maxZoom( $opt ) { 

  $opt['map']['maxZoom'] = 16;

  return $opt;

}
```