# html + google.maps.InfoWindow() + external source xml document (XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: javascript, html, xmldocument

I have a HTML page which hosts a google maps info control. I am able to display a marker giving static values hard-coded in the html document. Now i am trying to get the values from a  XML external source document. This is what I want to do,

```
function initialize(Object) {

var mapOptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.314059,84.801407),
zoom: 13,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
marker:true
};

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
var LatLat = x[i].getElementsByTagName("COUNTRY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
var LongLong = x[i].getElementsByTagName("COMPANY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
var Title = x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(LatLat, LongLong);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatlng,
map: map,
title: Title
});

}
}
```

The xml document,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Ambupa Bauri Street</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>56</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>19.3173287566233</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>84.8497137612449</COMPANY>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Anadrigam</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>64</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>19.3128836507433</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>84.7996238277367</COMPANY>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

My  tag is as below,

```
<body onload="if (onLoad) onLoad(); initialize()">
```

This is not working, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: remove "if (onLoad)" from body onload function. i think it might be issue with that

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did add the onload function call on a button click event.  <input type="button" onclick="initialize()" value="Call function"> Still unable to get the marker on the google maps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all code will not work well because there are some bugs in it. like you have not mentioned event listener for markers for info window like that.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
return function() {
  infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
})(marker, i));
```

You can find reference from

[Google Maps API v3: auto-center map with multiple markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719951/google-maps-api-v3-auto-center-map-with-multiple-markers)

Or

http://wrightshq.com/playground/placing-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-using-api-3/

Please look into this FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/x5R63/

**EDIT FOR FURTHER ANSWER **

```
//GET NODE LENGTH
function getNodeLength(nodeName, xmlNode){
    return xmlNode.getElementsByTagName(nodeName).length;
}

//GET NODE VALUE
function getNodeValue(nodeName, xmlNode, i){
    return xmlNode.getElementsByTagName(nodeName)[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
}

function getExtendedNodeValue(nodeName, xmlNode, i)
{
    var node = "";

    if(typeof(xmlNode.getElementsByTagName(nodeName)[i]) != "undefined" && xmlNode.getElementsByTagName(nodeName)[i].hasChildNodes())
    node = xmlNode.getElementsByTagName(nodeName)[i].firstChild.nodeValue;

    return node; 
 }


 function getAttributeValue(i, nodename, data){
    return data[i].getAttribute(nodename);
 }
```

Now based on your situation you can use above code like below:

```
var len = getNodeLength(xmlDoc,"CD");

for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
   var latLat = getExtendedNodeValue("COUNTRY",xmlDoc,i);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, I kinda understand the issue, I am able to get the marker on the map when i directly substitute values to var LatLat = "19.333"
var LongLong = "35.333"
var Title = "Orissa", but i think i am unable to get the info stored in the xml document. Can you please help me and show me how can i open the xml and read the info and put that into a for look and display it on google maps? Thanks again.