# How to show the markers in center screen in Android Google Map ClusterItem

Tags: java, android, google-maps

How to show the markers in center of screen in [Android Google Map Cluster](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/)?

I have an existing application that uses [Marker](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker) in current application, unfortunately there is no straight way to add [Marker](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker) to cluster. I have to convert those [Marker](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker) into [ClusterItem](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/) instance.

My problem is that how can I show those ClusterItem in center of screen?

Comment: This link might help you: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719951/google-maps-api-v3-auto-center-map-with-multiple-markers). Also, you may check the Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering?hl=it

Comment: This is not javascript, this is for Android. This is not marker, this is ClusterItem.