# Google maps fitBounds() does not work as expected

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, fitbounds

I try to zoom to a number of km on a location (Paris, in my case), like this:

```
map.myCircle = circle;

// update radius
map.myCircle.radius = newRadius;

// update map - ZOOM
map.myCircle.setMap(null);
map.fitBounds(map.myCircle.getBounds());
map.myCircle.setMap(map);
```

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbmKZz?editors=001)**

This gives 
[image]

As you can see, the `fitBounds` does not really fit the circle bounds.

When you increment (up-down) the radius, you can see that the map zoom does not change, but the circle radius changes.

Is there a way to synchronize the view zoom with the circle radius and make the circle touch the map margins?

Comment: If you make your radius large or small enough, the zoom will adjust. For example, if you change your radius to less than 64km or more than 128km, the zoom will change to fit your circle. Seems like its working to me.

Comment: I need to zoom *at each* radius change, not just by big steps

Comment: Have you tried to create a [zoom listener](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2990316/668148)?

Comment: @BogdanKobylinsky: I tried in the codePen, but don't see any difference...

Comment: @Serge the map zoom level doesn't allow you to adjust in tiny increments that you'd need if you wanted the bounds to exactly fit your radius, if you're just adjusting it by 1km at a time.

Comment: @duncan is right. But the documentation is not very clear. I think instead of saying *Sets the viewport to contain the given bounds* it should say *Sets the viewport to contain the given bounds using the most appropriate zoom level*. Or something like that ;-)

Comment: As for me, the zoom for the circle in the provided screen (65km) is not very *appropriate*...

Comment: hey, did you solve this problem ?

Comment: @MayK I think there is no solution, as I understood the google map zoom is "step by step", not continuous... so there is a max zomm, say 1km, the others will be 2km, 4km, 8 km... so there is any possibility to set a 5km zoom...